# Run a .bat file from a Python CGI file with Apache Webserver

Tags: python, windows, apache, batch-file

This might be really easy. But its just not working for me.

I have a .bat file I would like to run, which performs stuff on the Server, and should send an email with an Attachement.

The .bat file works fine, it sends the email with the log and everything.

Now I would like to run that file from a Webserver. So that I can click on an HTML form Button, and it executes.

I have installed Apache, Python 2.7 for it.

I have configured Apache to allow cgi files, and It works when I put a file as index.py with following code.

But when I press the Submit button it goes through, but the .bat files is not being executed. Help! :)

Is there another way I can run a .bat file to do stuff on my server from a Webserver maybe? thank you in beforehand.

I tried the action in the form to direct to a .py and .cgi file... don't get it to work

Below the code I a have been using.

```
#!/Python27/python
#!/usr/bin/env python
import cgi
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()  
print "Content-type: text/html"
print
print "<html><head>"
print "<form action='../cgi-bin/send_email.py'>"
print "<input type='submit' value='Submit'>"
print "</form>"
```

send_email.py looks like this.

```
#!/Python27/python
#!/usr/bin/env python
import cgi
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()

from subprocess import Popen

p = Popen("batch.bat", cwd=r"C:\Path\to\batchfolder")
    stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke the batch file with `cmd.exe`:

```
...
cmd     = r'c:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe'
batDir  = r'C:\Path\to\batchfolder'
batName = r'batch.bat'
p = Popen(r"{0} /C {1}\{2}".format(cmd,batDir,batName), cwd=batDir)
...
```